# How to execute batch scripts inside stored procedures?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm doing Integration work through stored procedure. So when I get an error I need to transfer my files to some location.

I have a Windows batch file and I need to execute that batch file using a stored procedure, which means I need a query to be used inside that stored procedure to execute that batch file. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xp_cmdshell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms175046.aspx), e.g. `xp_cmdshell 'dir *.*'`

Maybe you have to activate that SP:

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'c:\path\file.bat'
```

Should work just fine as long as xp_cmdshell is enabled, as per Ocaso's code. Of course xp_cmdshell is a scary little beast that should only be enabled if all other options have been exhausted. Consider this very scary batch file, for existence:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Database info
REM User must have xp_cmdshell exec privileges
SET "user=username"
SET "pass=password"
set "servername=192.168.1.100"
set "database=database_name"
IF EXIST thiscmd.sql DEL /F /Q thiscmd.sql

ECHO SET NOCOUNT ON > thiscmd.sql
ECHO create table #result (outputrow varchar(200)) >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO Insert into #result >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO exec master..xp_cmdshell '%~1' >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO declare @thisline varchar(200) >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO declare output_cursor CURSOR FOR  >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO select * from #result >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO OPEN output_cursor >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO FETCH NEXT FROM output_cursor into @thisline >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO BEGIN >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO    print @thisline >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO    FETCH NEXT FROM output_cursor into @thisline >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO END >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO CLOSE output_cursor >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO DEALLOCATE output_cursor >> thiscmd.sql
ECHO drop table #result >> thiscmd.sql

.\osql -n -U%user% -P%pass% -S%servername% -d%database% -w200  -i thiscmd.sql

IF EXIST thiscmd.sql DEL /F /Q thiscmd.sql
```

Assuming the username and password provided have xp_cmdshell access, that batch file essentially gives you a remote command prompt running as whatever user owns the SQL service. This means that if someone compromises one SQL user they've compromised the entire server. I have similar batch files that automate the net commands to move files back and forth and I guarantee you any attacker worth his/her salt will also.

TL;DR: USE WITH CAUTION! xp_cmdshell is DANGEROUS.